# Canvas with glsl shader breaks at certain css transform scale

Tags: css, canvas, webgl

I have a canvas with a shader on it, to do that I am using [glslCanvas](https://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas), and I want to transform that canvas with css transform. This works fine in general, but when I scale it such that it becomes significantly bigger, the shader freezes.

I tried to discover what causes this, but had no luck so far. It seemed I can do `scaleX` however large I want but not with `scaleY` or `scale`. I checked if there was a certain resolution or scale where it freezes but haven't found any result, it depends on the size of the canvas.

### Minimal example

Here is an example where the canvas gets enlarged incrementally, and breaks on `scale(4)`. Starting the canvas at `scale(4)` instead of incrementally increasing just results in a white canvas.

```js
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('glsl').style.transform = "scale(2)", 2000);
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('glsl').style.transform = "scale(3)", 5000);
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('glsl').style.transform = "scale(4)", 8000);
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('glsl').style.transform = "scale(5)", 12000);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/master/dist/GlslCanvas.js"></script>
<canvas id="glsl" class="glslCanvas" data-fragment="

precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

void main()
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    // Time varying pixel color
    vec3 col = 0.5 + 0.5*cos(u_time+uv.xyx+vec3(0,2,4));

    // Output to screen
    gl_FragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}"></canvas>
```

I'm not sure whether this is specific to the glslCanvas library or not, but haven't found any issues regarding this topic on their repository on Github.

Comment: I'd say its a browser bug, doesn't happen on my linux in chrome.

Comment: Investigating this led me to an issue with glslCanvas. You can see a bit more information on the PR I submitted: https://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/pull/47

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Investigating this led me to uncovering an issue with glslCanvas.

The PR I submitted is here: http://github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/glslCanvas/pull/47

Essentially, scaling can cause the code to falsely believe that the canvas is not visible, and so it stops rendering.

Comment: Just tried out your fork, and it works like a charm, thanks a lot!